# Left join with multiple inner join

Tags: sql

How can we make multiple left and inner join in SQL Server

Following query not returning all Employees because of Inner join

```
SELECT * from Employee E 
            LEFT JOIN Participants P on E.EmpID=P.EmpID
            INNER JOIN HRDetails H on D. DeptID=H.DeptID
            Left JOIN SalaryDetails S on S.participantID=P.participantID
```

Comment: If they do not exist in HRDetails it will not return records.  Can change that to LEFT JOIN as well.  If you need it to be INNER JOIN please provide data examples.

Comment: In most cases after the first OUTER JOIN all subsequent should be OUTER as well.

Comment: Where's table `D`?

Answer (score 0):

You have used an alias D. which does not refer to any table, this may cause error.

But to answer your question I think inner join would reduce the number of rows if not all DeptID matches between two tables.